# Why would 'quamquam' have been employed in school debates?

Tags: etymology, french

[Wiktionary in English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cancan#French) lacking information on etymology, I must cite [the French version of the French verb 'cancan'](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cancan#fr), but omit the other impertinent etymology hypotheses:

> (Bavardage) (1821) [3.] Désignant d’abord un « grand bruit à propos de quelque chose »,
>   [2.] dérivé du [quanquan](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quanquan) de collège (vers 1640),
>   [1.] dérivé du latin [quamquam](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quamquam#la) (« quoique »), conjonction souvent employée dans les débats d’école.

I recognise Latin's being the lingua franca until 1850-1900, and so Latin would have been spoken even by French students before 1640 (as dated above).

4. Per 1, what is special about 'quamquam', compared to [any other conjunction](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_conjunctions)? E.g., English has borrowed cum and ergo, but they have not been derived into verbs.
5. How would the explanation above explain the semantic shift for 'cancaner' (= to gossip)? What semantic notions underlie the use of quamquam with 'cancaner'?

Comment: "1 CANCANER v. intr. (1654) semble avoir été créé, non pas d’après cancan, mais d’après une onomatopée homonyme évoquant le cri du canard et de certaines volailles (→ canard) et d’après cane, cancan, nom enfantin du canard. Il s’est surtout répandu à partir du xixe s. avec l’idée de « médire » (1829)" ( Dictionnaire historique de la langue française 2017)

Comment: If the debate is a free-for-all, *quamquam* has three advantages for the student thinking on his/her feet: it takes the indicative not the subjunctive; it starts with a good strong plosive; and it signals a disagreement, counter-argument without the offensiveness of *haudquaquam,* or an absolute rebuttal.  The English equivalent is *Surely, ...*

Comment: For those of us who don't speak French, could you provide a translation into English?

Comment: Can you explain why you think *quamquam* would be "special" and not just part of a historical accident?

Comment: because quamquam has a funnier sound than the other conjunctions

Comment: Maybe related: [the kiskis and kankan debate: primary sources](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16910)