# the kiskis and kankan debate: primary sources

Tags: pronunciation, new-latin, history

There's a very famous story about how in the middle of the sixteenth century the Sorbonne University filed a legal claim to the Parlement de Paris  re: the correct pronunciation of qu- in Latin, viz. in the words quisquis and quamquam (e.g. Waquet 2001: 166  [Latin or the empire of a sign](https://www.versobooks.com/books/839-latin), English translation by John Howt, the original book in French [Waquet 1998](https://www.albin-michel.fr/ouvrages/le-latin-ou-lempire-dun-signe-9782226106797)). Voltaire even called one of his essays  ["Du mot quisquis de Ramus, ou de la Ramee"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Questions_sur_l_encyclop%C3%A9die_par_des_am/wX9dAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=du%20mot%20Quisquis%20de%20Ramus&pg=PA203&printsec=frontcover), published in 1772.

The traditional practice at the Sorbonne at the time was to pronounce such words as [kiskis] and [kankan], whereas [Petrus Ramus](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/term/BIOG146698) defiantly taught his students to "heretically" pronounce these words with [kw]. The Parlement de Paris famously ruled that anyone was allowed to pronounce qu- in Latin as they pleased.

My question is, are there any extant documents from the hearing? It would be quite interesting to read the primary sources.

Comment: This seems like an interesting and on-topic question to me. (It's borderline, but I think the connection to Latin is strong enough.)

Comment: Yeah, this is fine. I think you're more likely to get someone who knows this story from French.SE, but I'd say it's on topic here, too (and not just because it's interesting!).